# Comparison of Integer with nil failed in quicksort helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, data-structures, quicksort

I am trying to sort a random array of 15 element before creating a Binary Search Tree using Quicksort and an error pops up. I can't seem to find where the problem is.
This is the error:

```
C:/Users/K/Desktop/odin/FullStack/Ruby_on_Rails/Ruby/projects/binary-search-trees/lib/tree.rb:197:in `<=': comparison of Integer with nil 
failed (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Users/K/Desktop/odin/FullStack/Ruby_on_Rails/Ruby/projects/binary-search-trees/lib/tree.rb:197:in `block in partition'    
        from C:/Users/K/Desktop/odin/FullStack/Ruby_on_Rails/Ruby/projects/binary-search-trees/lib/tree.rb:194:in `each'
        from C:/Users/K/Desktop/odin/FullStack/Ruby_on_Rails/Ruby/projects/binary-search-trees/lib/tree.rb:194:in `partition'
        from C:/Users/K/Desktop/odin/FullStack/Ruby_on_Rails/Ruby/projects/binary-search-trees/lib/tree.rb:181:in `quick_sort'
        from C:/Users/K/Desktop/odin/FullStack/Ruby_on_Rails/Ruby/projects/binary-search-trees/lib/tree.rb:185:in `quick_sort'
        from C:/Users/K/Desktop/odin/FullStack/Ruby_on_Rails/Ruby/projects/binary-search-trees/lib/tree.rb:10:in `initialize'
        from ./lib/main.rb:5:in `new'
        from ./lib/main.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

The quick sort method is :

```
def quick_sort(array, s, e)
    if s < e
      p = partition(array, s, e)
      quick_sort(array, s, p - 1)
      quick_sort(array, p + 1, e)
    end
    array.uniq!
    array
  end
```

The problem is in the helper method below:

```
 def partition(array, s, e)
    x = array[e]
    i = s - 1
    (s...e).each do |j|
      next unless array[j] <= x

      i += 1
      swap(array, i, j)
    end
    swap(array, (i + 1), e)
    i + 1
  end
```

In full the code looks like this:

```
def quick_sort(array, s, e)
    if s < e
      p = partition(array, s, e)
      quick_sort(array, s, p - 1)
      quick_sort(array, p + 1, e)
    end
    array.uniq!
    array
  end

 def partition(array, s, e)
    x = array[e]
    i = s - 1
    (s...e).each do |j|
      next unless array[j] <= x

      i += 1
      swap(array, i, j)
    end
    swap(array, (i + 1), e)
    i + 1
 end

def swap(array, i, j)
    temp = array[i]
    array[i] = array[j]
    array[j] = temp
    array
  end
```

Comment: Do some basic debugging. You know the line on which the error occurs, so check that the values involved are what you think they are. Work backwards from there. If you can't figure it out, produce a **minimal** example that reproduces your problem, along with input.

Comment: I have tried that, that's why I am here

Comment: `array.uniq!` modifies the array, but your boundaries `s` and `e` stay the same. if you have duplicate numbers in the array, sometimes `e` goes out of bounds and `array[e]` returns `nil`. for example `quick_sort([2,3,2,1],0,3)` fails, but `quick_sort([2,3,2,4],0,3)` succeeds. try returning `array.uniq` in `quick_sort` and remove `array.uniq!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem was in the destructive method uniq! in the quick_sort method which modifies the array, but the boundaries s and e stay the same.
I changed it to return the uniq elements in the array.
Here is the answer

```
def quick_sort(array, s, e)
    if s < e
      p = partition(array, s, e)
      quick_sort(array, s, p - 1)
      quick_sort(array, p + 1, e)
    end
    array.uniq
  end
```